# Terminal não reconhece packages/modules personalizados automaticamente

Tags: python, pycharm, packages, import, módulo-python

Tenho esse projeto criado no meu PyCharm.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No arquivo de teste (test_inicio.py), faço o import normalmente do arquivo inicio.py como:

`from grande_pack.utils.inicio import soma`

No entanto, ao realizar o teste pelo terminal com `python -m unittest test_inicio.py`, é retornado o erro `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'grande_pack'`.

Eu já tentei:

- Marcar as pastas testando_imports_raiz e grande_pack como Source Root
  pelas configurações do PyCharm (nesse caso, o erro muda para
  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'`) (também já confirmei que nas configurações do PyCharm estão marcadas as opções de adicionar conteúdos da source root para PYTHONPATH)
- Fechar o PyCharm, apagar a pasta .idea, reabrir o projeto como novo projeto
- Verificar se os modules e os **init**.py estão sendo reconhecidos como arquivos python pelo PyCharm

Quando eu uso o comando `export PYTHONPATH=` com o local da source root, funciona. Então, me parece que o problema não é exatamente do PyCharm, mas sim algo referente à configuração do PYTHONPATH. Então acho que a pergunta aqui é: eu preciso exportar a variavel sempre que criar um novo projeto, ou existe alguma forma de fazer com que essa source seja automaticamente reconhecida ao criar projetos pelo PyCharm?

Comment: crie um setup.py dentro do pacote e adicione todos os paths do seu modulo [Doc setup.py](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html)

Comment: Mas isso não teria que ser feito em todo novo projeto, de qualquer forma?

Answer (score -1):

Você tentou importar da seguinte forma?

```
from .grande_pack.utils.inicio import soma
```

Ou então você pode configurar um setup.py a partir desse link: https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).